# Coldfusion: How to print out data from query

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to make a configureable print out of a query.

```
<cfloop query="#query_name#">
   <tr class="tabledetail">
       <cfloop array="#col_db_names#" index="colname">
           <td valign="middle" class="detaildata" nowrap>
               #query_name#.#colname#
           </td>
       </cfloop>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
```

The problem is, that i can't figure out how to display the data now, because i only get this output:

[image]

Thank you for your help, I'm still quite new to ColdFusion.

Comment: https://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Data_Handling/item/Databases.html - prob worth learning things a bit more.

Comment: _HINT_ - you are looping over the array of col_db_names and printing those out for each iteration of the main query loop.  That's why you are getting that output. I would recommend using the `<cfdump var="#query_name#">` tag outside of the loops to see what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you go through https://www.learncfinaweek.com/ if you need help with the language. Looks like you've got the basic concepts of how to organize the output. I thought it was missing the actual `<cfoutput>` tags, but then I realized the syntax inside the `<td>` tags.

```
#query_name#.#colname#
```

This is evaluating the two variables separately. The query name
and the column name from the array. This is why you're seeing the names of each column in the HTML table.

The syntax to reference the column name as an element of the query is

```
#query_name[colname]#
```

This should output the data in each column in the HTML table cells.

Comment: Thank you, also for the website! That worked! In the end I chose to give the query a fixed name, so I could use that syntax:

#s_query["#colname#"][currentrow]# (Where s_query is a fixed name for my Query)

If anybody else needs something like this:
https://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/03/15/Outputting-a-ColdFusion-query-dynamically

Comment: Given that this answer worked for you, the courteous thing to do is to mark it as the correct answer.